# Разрешить выбирать только некоторые дни

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть ли способ ограничить выбор дней в `dateTimePicker`, мне необходимо что бы пользователь мог выбрать только последние 4 пятницы от текущей даты.

Comment: в стандартном вроде нельзя, он только совсем базовые функции предоставляет. Разве что наследоваться и грейдить руками, или сторонний компонент использовать

Answer (score 1):

1. Сторонний компонент
2. Написать свой компонент унаследованный от оригинала и доработанный тобой лично.

Есть еще вариант костыля -- никак не подсвечивать возможные варианты и просто не давать применять даты, которые не соответствуют каким-то твоим условиям. Но так лучше не делать. Это не юзер-френдли.

Comment: Сделал через comboBox.